# How can I setup a "remote" repository on a separate drive and clone that repository to work on in another drive with git versioning control?

Tags: git

I'm still trying to learn how to use git so bear with me.. I want to have a "remote" repository on my back up drive and just clone it onto another drive where I can develop on my stuff. Once I'm happy with what I have, I want to be able to push it back to that "remote" repository on my backup drive. Basically have github on my machine without having to put my stuff on the web. Is this even possible? If so what would be the right way to do this. Thank you.

Comment: Git goes through your OS's file system setup, so for physically mount-able drives (e.g., USB thumb drives) just use whatever place your OS puts them: drive letters on Windows, /Volumes on macOS, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your remote drive is mounted at `/mount/git-repos/my-repo`, you can just clone from that path:

```
$ git clone /mount/git-repos/my-repo
```

and work with the cloned repository as usual. Just make sure the remote drive is mounted before pushing.